# CONNECT ERROR: PHP Extensions “zlib” must be loaded

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, magento

While Magento installing Extension and themes and also trying to upload, i am getting

> CONNECT ERROR: PHP Extensions "zlib" must be loaded.

I have tried to installed zlib from there https://www.namhuy.net/2430/install-enable-zlib-linux-server.html

zlib is insalled in My Ubuntu [image]

Also enabled and loaded in PHP ini [image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Go to `downloader/lib/Mage/Archive/Helper/File/` in your Magento directory

and edit the `Gz.php` file. You need to replace:

```
if (!function_exists('gzopen')) {
```

with

```
if (!function_exists('gzopen64')) {
```

and also:

```
"$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen($this->_filePath, $mode);"
```

with

```
"$this->_fileHandler = @gzopen64($this->_filePath, $mode);”
```